# Can a language ever have compile-time checking but the characteristics of dynamic typing?

Tags: java, c#, c++, oop, types

Upon reading the following:

> A lot of people define static typing and dynamic typing with respect
>   to the point at which the variable types are checked. Using this
>   analogy, static typed languages are those in which type checking is
>   done at compile-time, whereas dynamic typed languages are those in
>   which type checking is done at run-time.
>
> This analogy leads to the analogy we used above to define static and
>   dynamic typing. I believe it is simpler to understand static and
>   dynamic typing in terms of the need for the explicit declaration of
>   variables, rather than as compile-time and run-time type checking.

[Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/typing-versus-dynamic-typing/)

I was thinking that the two ways we define static and dynamic typing: compile-time checking and explicit type declaration are a bit like apples and oranges. A characteristic in all statically typed languages (from my knowledge) is the reference variables have a defined type. Can there be a language that has the benefits of compile-time checking (like Java) but also the ability to have variables unbounded to a specific type (like Python)?

Note: Not exactly type inference in a language like Java, because the variables are still assigned a type, just implicitly. This theoretical language wouldn't have reference types, so there would be no casting. I'm trying to avoid the use of "static typing" vs "dynamic typing" because of the confusion.

Comment: That article is not very good. In particular, the author mixes up "declaration", "definition" and "initialization", making most of it completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It just sparked the question: can there be a language that combines the idea of Python's dynamic typing but offer the benefits of compile-time checking too like Java?

Comment: Questions for you: how do you make the two "parts" of that language interact? How does the "typed" part deal with untyped values?

Comment: @Mat - it would be just like Python but do the checking at compile-time. My question is would this be possible?

Comment: How do you perform type checking at compile time if the types of the values are determined at runtime? You can't verify information you don't have.

Comment: @Mat, well I don't see why they need to be determined at runtime - can't a language like Python know from the return value from the constructor what the type is? There are probably examples where the actual type couldn't be determined at compile-time but I'd like to know an example of what that might be.

Comment: If it could it would be statically typed. Simplest example: `def foo(bar): return bar+bar.` What's the type of the return value? int? float? vector? matrix? something that you can't add so this should not compile? You won't know until code runs that calls this function with an actual value. (Imagine you're in the python command line, how can the compiler guess what you will call that function with?)

Comment: @Mat, you are absolutely right. I never thought of this! If at compile-time, though, it knows the what the input values of the function will be, it would be able to validate it, no? Or does that just become a complex mess?

Comment: You're starting to describe Haskell - fully type-infered (well, nearly) _statically typed_ language.

Comment: Your comments sound as if the C++11 `auto` keyword would meet your requirements. You write `auto var = f();` or `auto var = "xxx";`, and the compiler determines the type of `var`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl that's correct, except there's still a static type system. I'm saying why can't a compiler evaluate the actual type of all objects at compile-time given the entire source code? Instead it relies on declared types. Now this does have benefits of its own, such as explicit annotations for the programmer, but in this language, the same variable could be assigned a float, char, etc. while still maintaining type safety.

Comment: *"I'm saying why can't a compiler evaluate the actual type of all objects at compile-time given the entire source code?"* - `auto` comes very close, as do C++ templates. *"while still maintaining type safety"* - I don't see how. If I write `x = y;`, type safety means that the code won't compile if `x` and `y` are not of compatible types. With dynamic typing, the assignment would be explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There ***could*** be, but should there be?

Imagine in hypothetical-pseudo-C++:

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual Object invoke(const char *name, std::list<Object> args);
    virtual Object get_attr(const char *name);
    virtual const Object &set_attr(const char *name, const Object &src);
};
```

And that you have a language that arranges:

- to make Object class the root base class of all classes
- syntactic sugar to turn `blah.frabjugate()` into `blah.invoke("frabjugate")` and
- `blah.x = 10` into `blah.set_attr("x", 10)`

Add to this something combining attributes of boost::variant and boost::any and you have a pretty good start. All the dynamicism (both good and runtime bugs bad) of Python with the eloquence and rigidity (yay!) of C++ or Java. With added run-time bloat and efficiency of hash-table lookups vs. call/jmp machine instructions.

In languages like Python, when you call `blah.do_it()` it has to do potentially multiple hash table lookups of the string "do_it" to find out if your *instance* blah or its class has a callable thing called "doit" every time it is called. This is the most extreme late-binding that could be imaged:

```
flarg.do_it() # replaces flarg.do_it()
flarg.do_it() # calls a different flarg.do_it()
```

You could have your hypothetical language give some control over when the binding occurs. C++-like standard methods are crudely static bound to the apparent reference type, not the real instance type. C++ virtual methods are late-bound to the object instance type. Python-like attributes and methods are *extremely* late bound to the current version of the object instance.

I think you could definitely program in a strong static typed language in a dynamic style, just as you could build an interpreter in a language like C++ or Java. Some syntax hooks could make it look a little more seamless. But maybe you could do the same in reverse: maybe a Python decorator that automatically checks argument types, or a MetaClass that does it at compile time? [no, I don't think this is possible...]

I think you should view it as a union of features. **but you'd get both the best *and* the worst of both worlds**...

Answer (score 1):

> Can there be a language that has the benefits of compile-time checking (like Java) but also the ability to have variables unbounded to a specific type (like Python)?

Actually mostly language have support for both, so yes.  The difference is which form is preferred/easier and generally used.  Java prefers static types but also supports dynamic casts and reflection.

> This theoretical language wouldn't have reference types, so there would be no casting.

You have to consider that language also need to perform reasonably well so you have to consider how they will be implemented.  You could have a super type but this makes optimisation very hard and you code will most likely either run slowly or use much more resources.

The more popular languages tend to make pragmatic implementation choices.  They are not purely one type or another and are willing to borrow styles even if they don't handle them as cleanly as a "pure" language.

> what exactly do they allow the compiler or programmer to do that dynamic types can't?

It is generally accepted that the quicker you find a bug, the cheaper it is to fix.  When you first start programming, the cost of maintenance isn't high in your mind, but once you have much more experience you will realise that a successful project costs far more to maintain than it did to develop and fixing long standing bugs can be really costly.

static languages have two advantages

- you pick up bugs sooner rather than later.  The sooner the better.  With dynamic languages you might never discover a bug if the code is never run.
- the cost of maintenance is easier.  Static languages make clearer the assumption made when the code was first written and are more likely to detect issues if you don't have enough test coverage (btw, you never have enough test coverage)

Comment: That's very true, but where I have trouble understanding is the need for static types - what exactly do they allow the compiler or programmer to do that dynamic types can't? I never got the whole idea of the reason for making a reference have a type. This might be an extended answer, so if there's somewhere I can look to find the answer...

Comment: @rb612 Conversely, I have never understood how people put up with dynamic languages. ;)  If you didn't give a reference a type e.g. `Object` how would you use it in a safe or efficient manner?

Comment: That's definitely another good way to think about it! :D But from Wikipedia: "A programming language is said to use static typing when type checking is performed during compile-time as opposed to run-time. In static typing, types are associated with variables not values. " Thanks for your edit - is there a way you can explain why this is though, that static typing has types associated with variables?

Comment: @rb612 static types can be optimised by allocating the registers, or resources needed because it knows exactly what the type is and how much space is required.  What is you doubt about types? BTW All the languages you mention have both. `C` for example doesn't have as dynamic check for type.

Comment: A reference without an explicit type is just a pointer. What could you (or better, the compiler) do with that? Nothing until it is known what it is pointing at.  Knowing what it is pointing at is giving it a type.

Comment: It just seems like the compiler would be able to still ensure type safety without having declared types. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but If the compiler knows the source code, it should be able to evaluate (at compile time) the actual runtime type of the object and which methods will be called on which objects and if they will succeed. I've heard static type checking is very difficult as-is, but the essence of my question is why the compiler isn't able to determine the actual type until compile-time.

Comment: @rb612 many static compilers infer the type of a variable from in the declaration.  This is doesn't change whether the compiler is static vs dynamic. The compiler isn't always able to determine the actual type because either a) it doesn't have enough information or b) it could have multiple types or c) the type might not even exist at compile time, i.e. the actual class might not be written yet.

Comment: You can't do type checking at compile time on dynamically typed languages because determining what value a variable has at a particular point in a program, in the general case, is equivalent to the undecidable halting problem.

Comment: @BobSteinke The compiler can only check what is known at compile time at best and in many cases can't even check things you might think it could reasonably check at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. The difference here boils down to early binding versus late binding. Early binding means matching everything up on the binary level upfront, fixing it in code. The result is rigid, type-safe and fast code. Late binding means there is some kind of runtime interpretation involved. This results in flexiblility (potentially unsafe) at the cost of performance.

The two approaches are different on a technical level (compilation versus interpretation) and the programmer would have to choose which is desired when, which would defeat the benefit of having both in the first place.

In languages that use a (common) language runtime however you do get some of what you are asking for through reflection. But it is organized differently and still type-safe. It is not the implicit kind of binding you refer to but requires a bit of work and awareness from the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what is possible with static types that is impossible with dynamic types: nothing. They are both Turing complete

The value of static types is finding bugs early. In Python, something as simple as a misspelled name isn't caught until you run the program, and even then only if the line of code with the misspelling is run.

```
class NuclearReactor():
  def turn_power_off(self):
    ...

  def shut_down_cleanly(self):
    self.turn_power_of()
```